# Huffy Savannah Cruise bike

Tags: cruiser

[image]I have a beautiful old Huffy Savannah bike and would like to know how old it is. The serial number starts with a 4 but that doesnt help me. Is it 1984, 1994, 2004, etc??  I cannot seem to find anything online about this bike other than some other ones for sale.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  Is there a reason you actually need to know the bike's age?  Mostly what you need to know is what replacement parts to get, and those would rarely be what originally shipped with the bike anyway.  It looks to be in decent shape, so after making sure it's in good order, take it out and enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Its a moderately modern version of a fairly traditional design.

The rear derailleur suggests its in the last 20 years, and the one-piece crank implies its a lower-cost variation.

The alloy wheel rims also show is relatively recent - a 1984 era bike would have had steel rims.

The zip ties holding cables to down and top tubes are a bit anachronistic, and the left/front brake cable is flapping in the breeze - I'd loosely secure that to the other cables in front of the headset. 
Not sure if the handlebar has reflections or rust in the photo, could be either.

Looks like a loverly bike to me - as long as the moving bits move smoothly, and the brakes work reliably, then it should be an enjoyable ride for decades to come.

Answer (score 0):

Based on color, hardware, decals I'd say no not 80's it's a 90's Huffy/Huffman as that derailed was a 90's production. I have the same bike but with the male frame. Mine was made in 1994 by the S#

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  It might help if you posted a picture of your bike to compare to.  Also, how do you know how to decode the serial number?